# Creating and positioning a control with c# on windows phone

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I'm creating an app where a user is filling in a form with several text boxes. They can add or remove text boxes based on how many they wish. I'm having trouble with adding and positioning a new control. Here's what I have so far:

```
TextBox textOne = new TextBox();
textOne.Text = "Lorem ipsum";
textOne.Height = 20;
textOne.Width = 50;
textOne.Margin.Left = 20;
```

The problem is the final line where I try to set the margin to 20 and it says:
"Cannot modify the return value of 'System.Windows.FrameworkElement.Margin' because it is not a variable".

Am I not using the correct method (well clearly I'm not) or am I just going about this the completely wrong way?

Answer (score 1):

try it with `Thickness` object:

```
textOne.Margin = new Thickness(20, 0, 0, 0); // left, top, right, bottom
```

Comment: Builds fine but when I run it, it doesn't seem to appear on the emulator. Is there anything else I'd need to add to make it show?

Comment: @Nanor you need to add it to the a container. You probably have a Grid named `LayoutRoot`. Just type in `LayoutRoot.Children.Add(textOne);`